# Collapsed Visibility Within a WPF ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, visibility

I used a Style setter to stretch out my ComboBoxItem (and button) so that it spans the entire length of the ComboBox like so:

```
    <ComboBox >
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem >
            <DockPanel >
                <Button Content="My Button" />
            </DockPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

This works fine.  Now, I add an additional button within the same ComboBoxItem, but have it set to Visibility Collapsed.

```
    <ComboBox >
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem >
            <DockPanel >
                <Button Content="My Button" />
                <Button Content="My Collapsed Button" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </DockPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Now, the new button is invisible, but I expected my original button to still stretch the entire ComboBox, like it does with the above code.  However, it does not.  Why is this so?  Is there a solution for this?  I am using  DataTriggers to edit the Visibility property.

NOTE: I also get the same thing if I just set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" in the ComboBox.

UPDATE:  Ok, this actually has something to do with the DockPanel.  I changed it to a StackPanel, and it works as desired.  However, I suppose I'm still curious as to why my first button would not stretch the entire DockPanel if the second button is collapsed?

Comment: Try playing around with each of the buttons `Dockpanel.Dock` properties

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `DockPanel` id you change to `Grid` it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `DockPanel.Dock` property to `Top`

```
  <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,129">
      <ComboBox.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
          </Style>
      </ComboBox.Resources>
      <ComboBoxItem >
          <DockPanel >
              <Button Content="My Button" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
              <Button Content="My Collapsed Button" Visibility="Collapsed" />
          </DockPanel>
      </ComboBoxItem>
   </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm just used to using DockPanel for most things, I did realize it was DockPanel-related when I switched panel types.  I just assumed that since only one Button was visible at a time, and the other was collapsed, that I wouldn't need to set the Dock property.  But obviously not!